# Connection Refused - Cent OS7

Tags: linux, firewall, centos7, iproute

It seems that the OS is blocking the connection outbound, I'm just not sure if it's because on my config. As I cannot `yum install` or `curl` but it shows connection refused. I tried the below commands to check.

`netstat`
[image]

`curl`
[image]

`iptables`
[image]

`yum update`
[image]

`ip route`

[image]

`traceroute google.com -p 80`

[image]

`/etc/resolv.conf`

[image]

Comment: Is this on a virtual machine/container?  If yes, what are the firewall settings on the host?

Comment: @tetech - no it's not a virtual machine. Is there somehow I can test using a command?

Comment: What's in the OUTPUT iptables chain that was cropped off?  Can you ping 172.20.26.1?  Do outbound connections from other machines on the subnet work (i.e. is your router not handing NAT properly)?

Comment: What machine is at 172.20.26.1? Please describe it in detail. It looks like the problem is there, and not with your CentOS machine.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help guys. Yes, it seems that the issue is not in the CentOS Machine. It's the firewall from the network who's blocking it.